# Multiple builds from same code base in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm pretty new to Java and Eclipse coming from an iOS/xCode background. I have an iOS project that has 2 builds, 1 that uses a test server and 1 that uses a live server. In xCode this was simply a case of adding a new build target, a Preprocessor Macro, than using #ifdef in code to use separate url's for each build.
Porting this over to Android, I have this list of things I need to do each time I want to build/test between the 2 versions

```
TO SWITCH BETWEEN LIVE AND TEST
Rename Application Package com.mybus.myapp/com.mybus.myapptestserver (Right click, Android Tools, Rename Application Package).
Rename com.mybus.myapp folder to com.mybus.myapptestserver.
Change Map API key in manifest
Change SENDER_ID in BeginActivity.java (Notification app ID).
Search and change all references com.mybus.myapp/com.mybus.myapptestserver (Including SharedPreferences).
Change URL's in ConnectionHelper.java and PasswordResetConnection.java
Change icon and label in Manifest for Application & BeginActivity.
Remove crash reporter (ACRA) from MyApplication.java.
Change .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_test_launcher) & .setContentTitle("myapptestserver") in GCMIntentService.java
```

Surely there is an easier way to build seperate builds and allow them both on a device at the same time?

Comment: Just a note for anyone else reading this. The new Android Studio that was just announced by Google says this `The new project structure is due to the switch to a Gradle-based build system. This structure provides more flexibility to the build process and will allow multiple build variants (a feature not yet fully implemented).` This will hopefully make things a lot easier in the future :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Ant script to do this. Once you customise your Ant script to handle all these changes, you can get the final output by running the ant release command.

An small example from where you could start with. I have written a post about it. This ant script, doesn't change any values in files, but what it does, is outputs the final apk, with a chosen name format, and puts it in a specified folder.

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/09/automating-builds-on-android-part-1.html

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/09/automating-builds-on-android-part-2.html

**Disclaimer:** These are links to my blog posts.

Comment: Thank you, I have just read that and although it could be a starting point, it doesn't really address any of the changes I currently make for each build. I could possibly use a `DEBUG` var in my Application class for some of them, but the main one seems to be changing the Application Package name (which I think should automatically change the folder name too but it doesn't).

Comment: By Ant scripts, you could rename/copy/move folders, scan files, and replace your package names to whatever you want. Scan Java files, and replace variables values. You just have to write those scripts once.